# msbuild writelinestofile with special characters

Tags: encoding, msbuild

I am concatenating a collection of files in an `AfterBuild` task. I'm reading each file through:

```
<ItemGroup>
      <FileContents Include="$([System.IO.File]::ReadAllText(%(InputFiles.Identity)))" />
</ItemGroup>
```

And then writing it with `WriteLinesToFile` task:

```
<WriteLinesToFile File="@(OutputFile)" Lines="@(FileContents)" Overwrite="true" Encoding="utf-8" />
```

But the special characters as `ñ` are not being correctly written to the output file. I have tried several encodings (Unicode, windows-1251, iso-8859-2) with no success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the encoding of the source files. They were using `windows-1252`.
Special characters are correctly written if source files are encoding using `utf-8` (code page 65001) and `Encoding="utf-8"` in the WriteLinesToFile task.

In order to change the encoding I have found two ways. One is opening the file in Visual Studio and change the encoding via File => Advanced Save Options.

The following `C# script` changes the encoding for every file below a given directory:

```
new DirectoryInfo("path/to/files/")
    .EnumerateFiles("*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
    .Select(f => f.FullName)
    .ToList()
    .ForEach(file =>
        File.WriteAllText(
            file,
            File.ReadAllText(file),
            Encoding.UTF8)
    );
```